# AWS SageMaker Jupyter Notebook: Images not Showing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I'm currently trying to display some images using AWS SageMaker making use of its Jupyter Notebook app. However, all I'm trying to do is show the loaded images. I have written a function to do this but all I'm left with is the images index and image name on calling the function.

The function:

```
import glob
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_random_image(dir, condition):

    placeholder = ''
    
    if condition == 'n':
        placeholder = 'NORMAL'
    elif condition == 'p':
        placeholder = 'PNEUMONIA'
    else:
        raise Exception("Sorry, invalid condition")
        
    #folder to look through for images
    folder = f"./data/chest_xray/{dir}/{placeholder}/*.jpeg"
    img_paths = glob.glob(folder)
    #folders have different number of images in them
    max_length = len(img_paths)
    randomNumber = random.randint(0, max_length)
    
    for index, item in enumerate(img_paths, start = 1):
    
        if index == randomNumber:
            #print image path
            print(index, item)
            #image from folder
            image = plt.imread(item)
            readyImage = plt.imshow(image)
            return readyImage
```

Calling the function:

```
get_random_image("train", "p")
```

Example result:

```
2078 ./data/chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/person522_virus_1041.jpeg
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7fd89ab86090>
```

I've done various things from logging out/in to restarting the kernel; only one option and thats `python 3`.

Comment: try adding this line to the first cell of the notebook: `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. Interestingly when I've looked at other resources they've never put that in. I've always used it though outside of ```SageMaker```. Add your comment as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add line to the first cell (or before the first plt.show() call) of the notebook:

```py
%matplotlib inline
```

This a is a [magic function](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#magics-explained) in IPython.

According to [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html):

> With this backend, the output of plotting commands is displayed inline
> within frontends like the Jupyter notebook, directly below the code
> cell that produced it. The resulting plots will then also be stored in
> the notebook document.